# Aspx pages not rendering after upload to FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ftp, filezilla

I have an ASP.net webform project on Visual Studio 2015 that I want to deploy. 
I have a domain name with godaddy.com and I purchased the hosting service from web.com. 
Using FileZilla, I uploaded all the project's files to Filezilla using the username and hosting address provided by web.com. To clarify, I uploaded the contents of the project file (the pages, the bin file, the account file, etc..).

Here's the problem: the .aspx pages do not render at all. They appear as code only.

Any advice or suggestions or comments will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the Publish command in Visual Studio to upload the needed files (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/how-to-publish-Asp-Net-web-application-using-visual-studio-2/). Alternatively you can publish the project files in a local folder and use an FTP utility like Filezilla to upload them to the server afterwards.

Comment: It sounds like you need tutorial on setting up ASP.Net site on particular hosting provider and such question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Also, make sure you purchased a windows hosting account with IIS. I've seen many people accidentally purchase a unix hosting account without realizing the difference until this happens.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I followed the tutorial o the website you linked. It's still not working. Only the HTML is being rendered, but no asp control is being rendered.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick I purchased hosting with Web.com. I've contacted them and was told that the hosting service should suffice.

Comment: First, take a look at the programming languages tabs in the hosting page: http://web.com/hosting/website-hosting  There is no mention of ASP.Net or C#. Most likely the support people don't know what they are talking about but from their programming languages, I'd say this is a *NIX box and isn't capable of running asp.net webforms without adding in other things like Mono that aren't listed here. In essence, the hosting package is not going to run ASP.Net.